# Azure Functions not being displayed

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have two functions on Azure Functions but only one is displayed on Azure Portal.

Both functions works when acessed by URL.

I'm using docker, NodeJS, VSCode. Anyone knows why its happening?

Below is Visual Studio screenshot.
[image]
Below is Azure portal screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Did you push the second one?

Comment: What's function detailed version?

Comment: Can you try to deploy your code in new function instance on Azure?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Yes, I pushed and it's working fine.

Comment: @PankajRawat I created a new function and deployed my container, and now it's OK, It's showing 2 functions. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have post a answer. Can you [mark it as the answer](https://0730bowmanwindow.blob.core.windows.net/work/mark.png) of this question to end this question? This will help others who meet the similar problem. If you post yourself answer, I will delete it.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the contribution of UnbearableLightness and PankajRawat.

So the solution is create a new function instance on azure and then publish your function code to azure. And then it should work.(I met two other people who faced the same problem and they solved it in the same way.)